# GroovySpy of a kotlin class can not be carried to java during Spock test

Tags: java, kotlin, testing, groovy, spock

I am using groovy and Spock for unit test. What I want is after the line "reader.get(_ as Path, _ as String) >> fileA", I want to call reader.get() inside the Factory class and it still should return fileA. But it didn't and it just executed the real get() method.My test file is like this:

```
given:
def reader = GroovySpy(Reader)
def file = new File()
reader.get() >> file //For example, fileA

and:
def factory = new Factory(reader)

when:
...
```

In here, the Reader class is a kotlin file like this:

```
class Reader(
    private val repoConfig: FactStoreRepoConfiguration = FactStoreRepoConfiguration()
) {
    fun get(): File {
        //For example, by default it returns fileB
    }
}
```

but inside the factory, which is a java file, when I tried this:

```
public final class Factory implements StoreFactory {

    private final Reader reader;

    public Store create() {
        System.out.println(reader.get()); //Expect to see fileA here, but see fileB
        return new Store(reader);
    }
}
```

No errors were given.It should just print the file (fileA) I defined in "given" step, but it didn't and it actually executed the get method inside the Reader class and print fileB.

For debug, I added this in the test file:

```
given:
def reader = GroovySpy(Reader)
def file = new File(path.toString())
reader.get(_ as Path, _ as String) >> file //For example, fileA

and:
def factory = new Factory(reader)
print(factory.reader.get()) //Added to test, returns fileA here

when:
...
```

In the test, it print the file I set but still not work in when calling in the factory class. Is it because it is a kotlin class? Because I also mocked another java object and it still can be mocked in the factory class.

Comment: How are you creating `reader` inside `Factory`? I think you're going to need to create a simple example people can run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GroovySpy` only works for Groovy code, not when called from Kotlin or Java.
Furthermore, Spock can't mock final classes, which all of Kotlin classes are by default unless you `open` them.

You can work around the `final` restriction by using [spock-mockable](https://github.com/joke/spock-mockable/), which can remove the `final` modifier for your test runtime, while keeping it in place for the compilation and in production.